# Changing time format php

Tags: php, datetime

I need to get the date/time format produced from a date / picker which currently outputs in this format `06-15-2011 09:35:32`

The format I require is the same as what get produced from the function `time()` = `1308126939`

I have look everywhere for this answer and cannot find.

Comment: Not sure why people are marking this down - sure, for a PHP veteran this seems like an easy question - but not necessarily for someone who is just starting out.

Comment: I agree - people a far too quick to mark people down on this site - where would this site be without new people joining - sort it out!!!!

Comment: when there is [~4500 search results for "change time format php"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=change+time+format+php) there is no doubt that the OP didnt invest any research effort and that justifies a -1 per definition. This has nothing do to with being a "PHP veteran".

Comment: Besides, we dont "mark down **people**" but just the **questions** they ask. A downvote doesnt imply "you are a stupid newbie". It says your question "does not show any research effort,  is unclear or not useful".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [strtotime](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

```
echo strtotime('06-15-2011 09:35:32');
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) function which converts text datetime notation into Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp from [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) is a unix format representing the number of seconds since 1st January 1970.  It can be replicated in date() as `$timestamp = date("U");`

You should be able to convert it using the [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) command.

```
$myDate = "06-15-2011 0-9:35:32"

$timestamp = strtotime($myDate)
```

You can then go on to format that in other ways using the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.